# Chart with Plotly does not respect the data

Tags: python, plotly

I have two problems when I trying to generate a chart with Plotly. First: all bars have the same values, and do not respect the values passed in the "data" variable. Second, I would like to change the separator of the bar labels "." to ",".

Here's the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

data = [
    ['FT-Transformer', 0.8102, 'MLP', 0.7790, 'TabNet', 0.7904, 'TabTransform', 0.7960, 'FT-Transformer', 0.7989, 'TabNet', 0.8073],
    ['TabNet', 0.8101, 'TabNet', 0.7592, 'NODE', 0.7790, 'NODE', 0.7847, 'NODE', 0.7904, 'NODE', 0.7818],
    ['NODE', 0.7989, 'NODE', 0.7535, 'TabTransform', 0.7677, 'TabNet', 0.7818, 'MLP', 0.7904, 'FT-Transformer', 0.7790],
    ['MLP', 0.7932, 'FT-Transformer', 0.7375, 'MLP', 0.6742, 'FT-Transformer', 0.7648, 'TabNet', 0.7705, 'TabTransform', 0.7592],
    ['TabTransform', 0.7705, '1D-CNN', 0.7365, '1D-CNN', 0.6685, 'MLP', 0.7082, 'TabTransform', 0.7677, 'MLP', 0.7535],
    ['1D-CNN', 0.6799, 'TabTransform', 0.7337, 'FT-Transformer', 0.5864, '1D-CNN', 0.5609, '1D-CNN', 0.7025, '1D-CNN', 0.7082]
]

strategies = ['TA/HI', 'PCA', 'SA', 'UNDER', 'OVER', 'AUMENTADO']


architectures = ['1D-CNN', 'FT-Transformer', 'MLP', 'NODE', 'TabNet', 'TabTransform']

colors = {
    '1D-CNN': '#1f77b4',        # Azul
    'FT-Transformer': '#ff7f0e', # Laranja
    'MLP': '#2ca02c',            # Verde
    'NODE': '#9467bd',           # Roxo
    'TabNet': '#8c564b',         # Marrom
    'TabTransform': '#d62728'    # Vermelho
}


fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(architectures)):
    y_values = []
    text_values = []
    color_values = []
    for j in range(len(strategies)):
        strategy = strategies[j]
        found = False
        for k in range(len(data)):
            for l in range(0, len(data[k]), 2):
                if data[k][l] == architectures[i] and data[k][l+1] > 0:
                    y_values.append(data[k][l+1])
                    text_values.append("<b>{:.2%}</b>".format(data[k][l+1]))
                    color_values.append(colors[architectures[i]])
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break
        if not found:
            y_values.append(0)
            text_values.append("<b>0.00%</b>")
            color_values.append(colors[architectures[i]])

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        name=architectures[i],
        x=strategies,
        y=y_values,
        text=text_values,
        textposition="outside",
        textangle=0,
        textfont=dict(size=10),
        marker=dict(color=color_values)
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(size=12),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.1,
    bargroupgap=0.05,
    legend=dict(orientation='h', yanchor='bottom', y=1.02, xanchor='center', x=0.5),
    margin=dict(t=200)
)

def format_percent(value):
    return "{:.2f}%".format(value).replace('.', ',')

for annotation in fig.layout.annotations:
    annotation.text = format_percent(float(annotation.text))

fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='.2%', separators=',')

fig.show()
```

I've tried several solutions, however, I still can't generate the desired chart, which consists of several bars, one for each strategy. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand how the data in your question relates to string lists and multiple lists, but I have processed the data with the understanding that your data represents string lists named strategies as columns and multiple lists as rows, and then created the graph. The data processing is in a data frame for easier handling later. The graph is drawn in a data frame extracted by architecture name in the newly created data frame. Next, the decimal point in the percentages is changed to a comma by replacing it with a comma in the text annotation.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(data)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i,s in zip(np.arange(0,data.shape[0],1), strategies):
    #print(np.array(data[:,i*2]))
    #print(np.array(data[:,i*2+1]))
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'strategies': s, 'architectures': data[:,i*2], 'per': data[:,i*2+1]})
    df_tmp['per'] = df_tmp['per'].astype(float)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_tmp])

fig1  = go.Figure()

for i,a in enumerate(architectures):
    dff = df.query('architectures == @a')
    fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=dff['strategies'],
        y=dff['per'],
        name=architectures[i],
        text=[str(x).replace('.', ',') for x in dff['per']],
        textposition="outside",
        textangle=0,
        textfont=dict(size=10),
        marker=dict(color=[colors[c] for c in dff['architectures'].values]),
    ))
fig1.layout.height=500
fig1.update_layout(font=dict(size=12),
                   plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                   barmode='group',
                   bargap=0.1,
                   bargroupgap=0.05,
                   legend=dict(orientation='h', yanchor='bottom', y=1.02, xanchor='center', x=0.5),
                   margin=dict(t=200)
                  )

   
fig1.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='.2%', separators=',')
fig1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing solution! Just one last question: is it possible to generate the graph in high resolution? I tried a few options, but nothing that would give me a satisfactory result.

Comment: You can increase the resolution by setting the scale to 1 or more in the image creation. The code specifies the following. `fig1.write_image('./data/write_scale.png', scale=2)` See here in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#change-image-dimensions-and-scale) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple problem in your code, first you should use a `dictionary` for your data, your `break` is misused is misused, your use of formatting is wrong and you need to provide a `d3-format` specifier string to `tickformat` in `yaxis`

Here is how I would change your code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

architectures = ['1D-CNN', 'FT-Transformer', 'MLP', 'NODE', 'TabNet', 'TabTransform']
strategies = ['TA/HI', 'PCA', 'SA', 'UNDER', 'OVER', 'AUMENTADO']

data = {
    'TA/HI': [('FT-Transformer', 0.8102), ('MLP', 0.7790), ('TabNet', 0.7904), ('TabTransform', 0.7960), ('FT-Transformer', 0.7989), ('TabNet', 0.8073)],
    'PCA': [('TabNet', 0.8101), ('TabNet', 0.7592), ('NODE', 0.7790), ('NODE', 0.7847), ('NODE', 0.7904), ('NODE', 0.7818)],
    'SA': [('NODE', 0.7989), ('NODE', 0.7535), ('TabTransform', 0.7677), ('TabNet', 0.7818), ('MLP', 0.7904), ('FT-Transformer', 0.7790)],
    'UNDER': [('MLP', 0.7932), ('FT-Transformer', 0.7375), ('MLP', 0.6742), ('FT-Transformer', 0.7648), ('TabNet', 0.7705), ('TabTransform', 0.7592)],
    'OVER': [('TabTransform', 0.7705), ('1D-CNN', 0.7365), ('1D-CNN', 0.6685), ('MLP', 0.7082), ('TabTransform', 0.7677), ('MLP', 0.7535)],
    'AUMENTADO': [('1D-CNN', 0.6799), ('TabTransform', 0.7337), ('FT-Transformer', 0.5864), ('1D-CNN', 0.5609), ('1D-CNN', 0.7025), ('1D-CNN', 0.7082)]
}

colors = {
    '1D-CNN': '#1f77b4',        # Azul
    'FT-Transformer': '#ff7f0e', # Laranja
    'MLP': '#2ca02c',            # Verde
    'NODE': '#9467bd',           # Roxo
    'TabNet': '#8c564b',         # Marrom
    'TabTransform': '#d62728'    # Vermelho
}

fig = go.Figure()

for architecture in architectures:
    y_values = []
    text_values = []
    color_values = []

    for strategy in strategies:
        strategy_data = data[strategy]
        value = next((item[1] for item in strategy_data if item[0] == architecture), 0)
        y_values.append(value)
        text_values.append("<b>{:.2%}</b>".format(value))
        color_values.append(colors[architecture])

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        name=architecture,
        x=strategies,
        y=y_values,
        text=text_values,
        textposition="outside",
        textangle=0,
        textfont=dict(size=10),
        marker=dict(color=color_values)
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(size=12),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.15,
    bargroupgap=0.1,
    legend=dict(
        x=0,
        y=1.0,
        bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
        bordercolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ),
    xaxis=dict(title='Strategy'),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Score',
        tickformat=".0%"
    ),
    title={
        'text': "Architecture Performance by Strategy",
        'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you continue your code please?

Comment: whoops, I updated my answer :)